# How to convert element to Z value using mean, std for each column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to know how to convert each column's value to some value using pandas and numpy.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

matrix = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

Original Matrix

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |

Output Matrix

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -1.22 | 2 | 3 |
| 0 | 5 | 6 |
| 1.22 | 8 | 9 |

For examples, column 'a' is [1, 4, 7].
'a''s mean is 4 and 'a''s std is 2.45
So, Output is [(1-4) / 2.45, (4-4) / 2.45, (7-4) / 2.45]

How to convert each values using pandas and numpy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
matrix = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=list('abc'))
```

If need processing all columns subtract all values by means and divide by [`DataFrame.std`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.std.html) with set `ddof=0`, because default is `ddof=1`.

```
df = df.sub(df.mean()).div(df.std(ddof=0))
print (df)
          a         b         c
0 -1.224745 -1.224745 -1.224745
1  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
2  1.224745  1.224745  1.224745
```

If need processing only one column:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].sub(df['a'].mean()).div(df['a'].std(ddof=0))
print (df)
          a  b  c
0 -1.224745  2  3
1  0.000000  5  6
2  1.224745  8  9
```